# Projection matrix orthogonalization

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

I have a projection matrix: $P = A(A^tA)^{-1}A^t$ where A's columns are base of a vector space V.

I understand that the projection must be done on a previously orthonomalized base, but I do not understand how $Px$ does that.

How does P orthonormalize the base?

Comment: An idea: Maybe it helps if you look at A as its singular value decomposition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), then it might become more apparent why P is a projection. Though I haven't gone through the whole thing myself.

Comment: @dasWesen the question is not why P is a projection though, it is how does it orthonormalize the base.

Comment: The SVD does two basis changes, with respect to orthonormal bases - M = UDV* where U and V are unitary, i.e. orthonormal bases. So it "moves" via V* into the basis where it scales the basis only, then moves back into a new basis via U. But maybe I misunderstood your question. Why and in what way does a projection have to be done on an orthonormalized base? You can choose a base (changing the representation of A and P), and typically you would use an orthonormal base. (E.g. euclidean - (1, 0, ..., 0) are orthonormal).

Answer (score 0):

Actually $P$ is an operator so it doesn't orthonormalize any vector.

Yet, you can choose a orthonormal basis on $V$ to express the matrix of $P$ in that basis.

Actually we like to make orthogonal projection which are projection that project a vector onto orthogonal basis.

For example :

$$ P :  f \in \mathcal{C}^0[0,1]\to \int_0^1 f(t)(1+\dfrac{1}{2}t) dt$$ an orthogonal projection from $\mathcal{C} ^0$ on $ Vect(1,\dfrac{X}{2}) $

$$ Q :  f \in  \mathcal{C}^0[0,1]\to \int_0^1 f(t)(1+t) dt$$ is a projection from $\mathcal{C} ^0$ on $ Vect(1,X) $
But not orthogonal because $(1,X)$ is not orthonormal for the scalar product $<f,g>=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt$

---

In your example you want $P$ to be orthonormal, so you have to make a Gram-Schmidt orthonomalization method on $A$ (which means the orthonormalization of the column vector of $A$ that are, as you mention here, a base of $V$.)

So let $R$  the orthonormalized matrix. $Q$ transition matrix from previous basis to $R$.

$$A=QRQ^{-1} \ \ RR^t=1 $$

$$P= QRQ^{-1}(QRQ^{-1}QR^{-1}Q^{-1})QR^{-1}Q^{-1}=Id$$

So $P$ must be the identity, that are the trvial orthogonal projection

For more precision you can look here :

Look here : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gram-SchmidtOrthonormalization.html  and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: "Actually we like to make orthogonal projection which are projection that project a vector onto orthogonal basis." What do you mean?

Comment: "Actually P is an operator so it doesn't orthonormalize any vector." P projects, thus it should orthonormalize at some point shouldn't it?

Comment: I mean that we can consider simple projection that aren't orthogonal projection, and so often less interesting than orthogonal one.

Comment: "I mean that we can consider simple projection" How can you project into a vector space with no orthonomalized bases?

Comment: It clearer now for you?

Comment: But $P$ is given as $P = A(A^tA)^{-1}A^t$, it must do some kind of orthonormalization to be able to give the correct result for $Px$.

Comment: I think my lecturer uses 'othogonality' as defined by the inner product $a^{t}a$ where a is a vector.

Comment: Yes so you want $AA^t=1$ for the base of $V$ you choose to be orthogonal.